# Disallow script execution but allow indexing?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Below is my Apache sites-enabled/default.conf

Basically I want to disallow **all** script execution but still allow users to see the index of /upload/anything. Users will be able to upload .ZIP files that will get extracted into www/upload. These could potentially include anything, like .htaccess files, .PHP files, etc.. Is it possible to show folder indexes but disallow all execution?

Hoping someone can provide me with an answer :)

```
<Directory /var/www/upload/>
            AllowOverride None

            SetHandler none
            SetHandler default-handler

            Options +Indexes -ExecCGI
            php_flag engine off
            RemoveHandler .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml .pl .py .pyc .pyo
            <Files *>
                    AllowOverride None

                    SetHandler none
                    SetHandler default-handler

                    Options +Indexes -ExecCGI
                    php_flag engine off
                    RemoveHandler .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml .pl .py .pyc .pyo
            </Files>
    </Directory>
```

Comment: The code you've included in your question would seem to be "the answer"? Does this not work? However, I see no reason for the `<Files *>` wrapper though? And dot files (eg. `.htaccess`) will likely be hidden/blocked by default.

Comment: Yep. It doesn't work :P

Comment: In what way "doesn't it work"? Do you get an error? Do you see a directory index? Are PHP files still processed? `.htaccess` files still processed? Presumably you have restarted your server?

Comment: I am getting the Apache 404 Not Found error instead of the generated index. Restarted several times!

Answer (score 0):

Sure that is possible, the auto generate index page apache http servers show has nothing to do with scripting. You can even remove all script executing modules loaded into the apache http server and still benefit from its generated index pages. And you can use the `AllowOverwrite` directive to prevent the interpretation of dynamic configuration files too, just take a look into the documentation.

*However* I doubt that you use a good approach here. Instead of relying on the http servers building file handling features you should use the combination of rewriting and routing to stay in control and handle all requests to uploaded files yourself. That way the whole question is irrelevant.